# unbindService vs. stopService

Tags: java, android

I have an single Activity application that starts a Service and binds to it.
I want the Service to continue to run even after I exit the Activity.

Right now I am doing a stopService then an unbindService.  My assumption is that I do need to unbind but to keep it running I shouldn't (obviously) call stopService, right?

I just want to know the proper service management techniques for a long running service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one can be answered from the Service documentation:

> Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed. See the Service documentation for more details on a service's lifecycle.

To clean up your service, it is good practice to unbind it.  You can always restart it again using another intent with a Context.startService().  Depending on how you use it, it might be optimal to start the service for a while, do some stuff, stop it (you can even use a call to stopSelf to do this), and then restart it again when you have more work to do -- or get another intent.

Comment: Understood.  I see the reason to unbind when the Activity finishes.  But the service keeps running even after I exit if I don't stopService on it, correct?

Comment: If you're not doing any work, it shouldn't matter, and it will just live around until the system naturally kills it.  This is no different than what happens with your activities as they sit on the stack of apps, anyway...

Comment: I am actually doing work in the service.  I am listening for home button presses and getting GPS fixes.  If I didn't need it I'd stop it of course.  Point being "unbind" unbinds the activity from the service, but stopService kills it.  In fact I am wondering why I even need to bind to it.

Comment: It's good practice.  By the way, you should _definitely not_ be catching the home button.  Users _really_ hate it when you do that.  Don't do that.  In the case that you only have one activity bound, that's fine, but unbinding will at least free up some space relating to maintaining the connection and it's overall good practice.  By the way, when you _are_ ready to exit, simply call a stopSelf()